# .Net Problem: Searching in .net table goes slow

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, blazor, webassembly

I am working on a Blazor Wasm project, and I have a problem in the performance of searching in a table (my table now has 3500 elements, but in production it can have 10000). I have to increase performance and I don't know how to do it. whether to approach it from C# or Javascript.

Iam using MudBlazor Components.

The Table in question:

```
<Virtualize Context="item" OverscanCount="50" TItem="ArticuloDto" Items="lArticulos">
  @if(FilterArticuloFunc(item))
  {
    <tr class="d-flex pa-2" style="border-bottom: 1px solid var(--mud-palette-tertiary);">
      <div class="flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-1 align-self-stretch">
        <MudText Typo="Typo.body1" Style="word-break: break-all;">@item.Descripcion</MudText>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.body2" Color="Color.Secondary">Codigo: @item.Codigo</MudText>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-shrink-0">
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h1" Align="Align.Right">$@item.Precio</MudText>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.body2" Align="Align.Right" Color="@StockToColor(item.ExistenciaActual)">Stock: @item.Existencia</MudText>
      </div>
    </tr>
  }
</Virtualize>
```

The FilterFunc in question:

```
private bool FilterArticuloFunc(ArticuloDto element)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchProductText))
    return true;
  if (element.Codigo.Contains(searchProductText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    return true;
  if (element.Descripcion.Contains(searchProductText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I would page it and search the source instead of relying on re-rendering on a per row basis.

Comment: Data should not be processed in the UI layer like this.  You should have a separate `List<ArticuloDto> FilteredItems`, and fill it using `FilteredItems = IArticulos.Where(a=> *some filter criteria*).ToList();`  Then use `FilteredItems` for your display.  --edit-- haha Alamakanambra already said exactly what I just said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have all the 3500 items loaded in memory. You fine with that?

50 overscan items is maybe too much. But your problem is somewhere else.

You do the filtering only on visible items, thus breaking the rule of same height of all items in virtualize component. If the height is different, it cannot count height of scroller properly. And it does a lot of rendering there.

I would suggest to create second list of `ArticuloDto` (`lArticulosFiltered`) and plug that into the virtualize component (`Items="lArticulosFiltered"`) and do the filtering like this:

```
lArticulosFiltered = lArticulos.Where(x=>x.Codigo.Contains(searchProductText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && x.Descripcion.Contains(searchProductText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

(on the beginning you have to assign `ArticuloDto` to `lArticulosFiltered`  )

You may hit another performance issues (for example you are doubling amount of memory needed to hold all items).

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use [Datatable side-server processing](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side) to solve these problem

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible, it has to work locally in the wasm without internet. That is a functional requirement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your description if the problem only happens while searching (like your title implies) or even at start up.

Because if it's only a searching problem it should be trivial to just dump the entire dataset in HTML and then do your searching in JavaScript, simply hiding or showing rows as needed.